# Python3 - How to tell if __idiv__ or __div__ behavior should be used when overloading __truediv__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I am working on some code that processes/parses binary data. Integer promotion is a requirement in my handling of various integer types. As a result of creating custom integer types AND because I want to support python2 and python3 (non-negotiable), I need to overload the `__div__`, `__idiv__`, and `__truediv__` operators.

However, in python3.7, I can't tell *why* **truediv** is being called! Example:

```py
class NewInt(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __div__(self, other):
        print("DIV")
        return self.value / other

    def __idiv__(self, other):
        print("IDIV")
        self.value /= other

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print("TRUEDIV")
        return self.value / other


test = NewInt(10)
test / 10
test /= 10
```

If run in python2.7, I get:

```
DIV
IDIV
```

If run in python3.7, I get:

```
TRUEDIV
TRUEDIV
```

How do I know when the in-place division is occurring if only `__truediv__` is being called?

Comment: `"support python2 and python3 (non-negotiable)"` FWIW, keep in mind that Python 2.7 will reach EOL in 2 months (1.1.2020)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not implement `__itruediv__` which is Python 3's equivalent to Python 2's `__idiv__`.

```
class NewInt(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print("TRUEDIV")
        return self.value / other

    def __itruediv__(self, other):
        print("ITRUEDIV")
        self.value /= other

test = NewInt(10)
test / 10
test /= 10
```

Outputs

```
TRUEDIV
ITRUEDIV
```